# Canon 6D CR2 Raw files don't work with Content-Aware Crop in Photoshop CC

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, raw, software, canon-6d

I've been trying to use the content aware crop tool in Adobe Photoshop to fill in some simple sections of the sky or foreground when I crop an image. Even with the Content-Aware checkbox checked the software doesn't fill in the areas it should. Selecting or de-selecting the checkbox has no effect on the crop.

This tool is only broken when I use Canon CR2 Raw files from my Canon 6D. When I use Content-Aware crop with JPEG or TIFF files it works fine. Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you can import the CR2 file in Photoshop, it is present as 8bits or 16bits RGB image, so your problem shouldn't be CR2 or 6D related.

Are you sure you are working with the layer containing your image ? This layer should be selected. Are you sure you're filling with content-aware, not anything else ?

Comment: I'll have to double check when I get home this evening but I've tried with the only layer being the freshly opened raw file (selected and locked/unlocked). I'll need to check as well if I'm filling the space with nothing on accident...

Comment: Sometimes with my stylet I touch the tablet and select 2-5 pixels, it's not visible and of course the filling is not visible; so yes, another point to check too ;)